# Select class that starts with a prefix and store full class name as variable

Tags: jquery

I need to find a class based on what the class name starts with, and then add the full class name to another element.

```
<div class="slide theme-light-blue">Test</div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

```js
var theme = $('[class^="theme-"]').filter(function() {
    return this.className.match(/(?:^|\s)theme-/);
});
$(".result").addClass(theme);
```

I think I got the first part by using regex to find all classes starting with "theme-", but I don't know how to store the full class name as a variable that can be added to another element. In this example I'm expecting the class "`theme-light-blue`" to be added to the `.results` div.
The code I have here is not working.
See [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/meek/wxka4L51/5/).

Comment: Argh, yes, my bad. Corrected.

Comment: Are you looking to apply this to multiple elements?

Comment: j08691: Yes, I might.

Comment: Can you update the HTML example to show a broader example of what you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should use the 'Attribute contains' selector to find elements which have a `theme-*` class, as it may not necessarily be the first class applied to the element. Your use of `filter()` is also incorrect as it's used to reduce a matched set of elements based on a supplied filter, and it returns a jQuery object, not a string.

To achieve what you require you can loop through the `classList` property of  each `.theme-*` element and apply that class to the next `.result` element in the page. Try this:

```
$('[class*="theme-"]').each(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.classList.length; i++) {
        if (this.classList[i].indexOf('theme-') == 0)
            $(this).next('.result').addClass(this.classList[i]);
    }    
});
```

[**Updated example**](https://jsfiddle.net/wxka4L51/8/)

This is obviously assuming that only one `theme-*` class is applied to an element.

Answer (score 0):

if you have second class in every case then you can use attribute getter( `attr()` ) to get class of your selection and split it with `split()`

```
var theme = $('[class^="theme-"]').attr('class')[0].split(' ')
         .filter(function(a){return a.match(/(?:^|\s)theme-/)
          })[0];
$(".result").addClass(theme);
```

Comment: What if the structure has more than one class which starts with `theme-`. First of all, the selector wont select any elements.

Comment: A.B.: I can't say for sure that it will always the the second class... However, I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined.

Raja: I understand, however, there will always only be one.

Comment: @Meek it will now work for other scenarios also for other cases also